# TypeScript - "not assignable to type never" error on Entity in Jest's mockResolvedValueOnce method

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I've seen this error being solved in primitive types but I am not sure how I would solve it in this example

```
const newUser: UserEntity = {
      user_id: 'f3bea6de-fb24-4441-b75b-d7642ca573d7',
      name: 'Test User',
    };

jest.spyOn(repo, 'create').mockResolvedValueOnce([newUser]); // error here on [newUser] - 'UserEntity' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

user.entity.ts

```
@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') user_id: string;
  @Column('text') name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`repo.create` is a synchronous function, but `mockResolvedValue` is for asynchronous functions that return `promise`s. Instead, use `mockReturnValueOnce` and you'll have no problems.

Comment: Well, in the tutorial i'm watching it uses `mockResolvedValue` but it gives me problem with the mocked `MongoRepository`.

Comment: `repo.create` is not specified in the original question so how did you know that it's synchronous. Changing it to `mockReturnValue` might real remove the error but I don't think that's the proper answer. I have scenario where that's happening on asynch fn

Comment: @kasongoyo I was only able to make the assumption it was synchronous due to A) the error that `mockResolvedValue` made Typescript error about a `never` return type and B) my knowledge of TypeORM and knowing that `create` only instantiates the entity class, it's `save` that is the async method.

Comment: Got it! I have added an extension to your answer that cover another scenario that's asynchronous. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're positive that the `repo.create` is asynchronous then you can use `mockImplementation(()=> Promise.resolve([newUser]))` to navigate that problem. Sometime that's happening because the mocked fn has both callback and promise version and the callback version shadows the promise one

Answer (score -1):

You can actually use `mockReturnValueOnce`. But when you need to return every time, `mockReturnValue` can be used.

Particularly for your case,

`jest.spyOn(repo, 'create').mockReturnValueOnce([newUser]);`